# Benchmarking HTTP/2 vs. previous protocol versions

Tags: performance, http, https, benchmarking, http2

I am working on comparing HTTP/2 against previous versions of the protocol, e.g. HTTP 1.1, SPDY 3.1. I have thoroughly researched the technical differences and I am now attempting to benchmark HTTP/2 against its previous incarnations. However, I am a bit stumped as to what the best way to do this is.

I have set up a Fedora server running [h2o](https://h2o.examp1e.net/) and have a test website on there that I am using for benchmarking. I am wanting to measure things like Page Load Time (PLT), total round trips/requests made, and total data transferred, specifically header sizes.

Is it possible to take accurate measurements for these metrics using a browser like Chrome or Firefox using developer tools, or will this be too heavily skewed by browser specific overhead? If so, what other tools could be used to accomplish this?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Most people seem to either measure things like page load time/first paint with their browser's web tools or they measure more raw HTTP transfer performance with a tool like [h2load](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/h2load-howto.html).

There are tools like http://http2.loadimpact.com/ that does it for you. (Ragnar also described his research on comparing h2 vs h1 on [his slides](http://www.slideshare.net/LoadImpact/http11-vs-http2-a-performance-analysis).)

Comment: Can you add some links to those studies @Daniel?

Comment: The "studies" would pop up the browser's web tools and check the network tab and see how long time things take, with h2 vs h1.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Those slides are neat!

Answer (score 1):

For the most part you can trust the metrics reported by the browsers, although they are terribly off when the server uses PUSH.

Since you control the website, you may take a look to the [user timing interface](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/usertiming/), it will make your life easier inside the browser.

More complex and involved alternatives are Wireshark network dumps and strace logs.

At the risk of being superfluous, I can add a couple of suggestions: try to use lab conditions. That is, run the server and the client in a network that you completely control. For example, a simulated network in your local computer, and then use [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) to simulate network parameters like rate and latency. If your server is in the Internet, the results of your measurements will be affected by factors that you don't control, like how many people is accessing the Internet in your city at that time of the day.